Enhance Debezium message sent to Apache Kafka with current logged in user identifier
I want to implement Debezium into my application to capture all the changes in selected tables in database (MSSQL). I do not have userId column in any table. Is it possible to intercept the message sent by Debezium to Apache Kafka and enhance it with the currently logged in user identifier?
I can't add userId (eg.: lastUpdatedBy) to the tables due to expected enormous amount of data

Sounds like you want to use InsertField transform from Kafka Connect?
